# Increase tomcat memory on Debian 7

Tags: tomcat, memory, debian

I have installed Tomcat7 on Debian Wheezy, the max memory is only 128Mo.
So I have tried to change the file /etc/init.d/tomcat7 by changing :

> if [ -z "$JAVA_OPTS" ]; then  JAVA_OPTS="-Djava.awt.headless=true
>   -Xmx128M" fi

by

> if [ -z "$JAVA_OPTS" ]; then  JAVA_OPTS="-Djava.awt.headless=true
>   -Xmx1024m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m" fi

After a restart of tomcat (command : "service tomcat7 restart"), the memory hasn't changed at all.
Is there another way to change it?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may edit it the file `/etc/default/tomcat7`; then find the line **JAVA_OPTS** and change it, example below:

`JAVA_OPTS="-Djava.awt.headless=true -Xmx1024m -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC`

Then restart tomcat 7:

`service tomcat7 restart`